# Android Webview not working like in browser

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I've build an app that uses webview for live-data chart, it opens the page just fine and charts x axis is also moving forward when time passes that means there's no problem with internet connection etc. but when it comes to data itself it's not present in chart, but in browser when I access to the same url it works perfectly, I'll put the screenshots of the two down below:

[Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCqET.png)

[Mobile Webview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUeak.png)

I have no clue what causing this or how can I solve this

I give access to all internet permissions and check urls and there seems no problem at all, my code is not giving any errors, I've only made some adjustments for url I'm using because of security protocols but that shouldn't cause the problem I'm facing right now, if it's gonna give more insight here's my code for webview

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun liveDataWebViewIntoAndroidApp() {
        binding.liveDataWebView.apply {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                // Handle API until level 21
                @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
                override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                    view: WebView?,
                    url: String?
                ): WebResourceResponse? {
                    return getNewResponse(url)
                }

                // Handle API 21+
                override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): WebResourceResponse? {
                    val url = request?.url.toString()
                    return getNewResponse(url)
                }

                private fun getNewResponse(url: String?): WebResourceResponse? {
                    return try {
                        val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
                        val request = Request.Builder()
                            .url(url!!)
                            .addHeader("X-EAE-Auth", BuildConfig.API_KEY)
                            .build()
                        val response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()
                        WebResourceResponse(
                            "text/html",
                            response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                            response.body!!.byteStream()
                        )
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        null
                    }
                }
            }

            val selectedSensorIds = ChartActivity.list.filter { it.isSelected }.map { it.sensorId }
            val finalUrl = StringBuilder("$URL?sensor_list=${selectedSensorIds[0]}")
            selectedSensorIds.drop(1).forEach {
                finalUrl.append("&sensor_list=$it")
            }

            Log.e("URL", finalUrl.toString())
            loadUrl(finalUrl.toString())
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            settings.apply {
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
                clearCache(true)
                setSupportZoom(true)
                setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                allowContentAccess = true
                domStorageEnabled = true
                loadWithOverviewMode = true
                useWideViewPort = true
                settings.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the all help, I2m still trying to learn this and trying to get every help I can get